# Bug when searching on the site, if the search keywords contains '+' character

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, encoding

If we include the `+` character when performing a search on any Stack Exchange site, all results contain lots of `&hellip;` characters (`…` encoded in HTML)

It seems to be finding lots of matches, because there are several tags like `<span class="search-highlight"></span>` without text inside.

Here is an screenshot:

[image: Search bug]

Comment: Browser bug, maybe? Firefox 3.0.6 and Chrome 11.0.696.48 show `…` as desired.

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Firefox 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build...we strip the + out, but it wasn't correctly ignoring the now-empty search term after that, and producing an invalid search pattern as a result.